# How can I remove extra slashes in my response using node?

Tags: node.js

How can I remove the extra slashes in my responses ?

I have tried `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` but they are not working in my code. `JSON.parse` throws an error like `json at position 10`.

I pushed the objects of responses in one array. Then I displayed the array of objects (with array) in response.

```
{
"status": true,
"message": "Data Found",
"data": [
"{\"errors\":[],\"detail\":[{\"repositories\":[],\"_instance\":{\"applicationLinkId\":\"4b0d5edc-c683-3502-aed7-5f6e152b877d\",\"singleInstance\":false,\"primary\":true,\"baseUrl\":\"http://stash.computenext.com\",\"name\":\"Stash\",\"typeName\":\"Bitbucket Server\",\"id\":\"4b0d5edc-c683-3502-aed7-5f6e152b877d\",\"type\":\"stash\"}}]}" 
] 
}
```

**My Code :**

```
exports.getCommits = function (req, res) {
  console.log(filename + '>>get commits>>');
  var response = {
    status: Boolean,
    message: String,
    data: String
  };
  var request = require('request');
  var username = username;
  var password = password;
  var options = {
    url: 'https://computenext.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=status+%3D+Resolved+ORDER+BY+updated',
    auth: {
      username: username,
      password: password
    }
  };

  request(options, function (error, obj) {
    if (error) {
      response.message = appmsg.DATA_NT_FOUND;
      response.status = false;
      response.data = obj;
      res.send(response);
    } else {
      response.message = appmsg.DATA_FOUND;
      response.status = true;
      response.data = JSON.parse(obj.body);
      //res.send(response);
      var respon = {
        status: Boolean,
        message: String,
        data: String
      };

      var issueKey = response.data.issues;
      var id = issueKey[0].id;
      console.log(id);

      var commitout = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < issueKey.length; i++) {
        var commits = issueKey[i].id;
        console.log(commits);

        var request = require('request'),
          username = username,
          password = password,
          url =
          "https://computenext.atlassian.net/rest/dev-status/1.0/issue/detail?issueId=" +
          commits + "&applicationType=stash&dataType=repository",
          auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString(
            "base64");

        //console.log(url);
        var test = [];
        request({
          url: url,
          headers: {
            "Authorization": auth
          }
        }, function (err, obj1) {
          if (obj1) {

            var info1 = obj1.body;
            commitout.push(info1);

            if (issueKey.length === commitout.length) {
              respon.message = appmsg.DATA_FOUND;
              respon.status = true;
              respon.data = commitout;
              res.send(respon);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Try parsing the following element</s>

```
commitout.push(info1);
```

change to,

```
commitout.push(JSON.parse(info1));
```

**Update**

Try the following regex

```
info1 = info1.replace(/\\/g, "");
commitout.push(info1);
```

Comment: I tried your above code. It throws the below error,                                                  undefined:11
<html>
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 10
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Request._callback (D:\Bhuvana\register\server\services\userService.js:201:31)
    at Request.self.callback (D:\Bhuvana\register\node_modules\request\request.js:186:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)

Comment: There is no errors but am not getting the expected. That above code also send the same response like mine.

Comment: I got the answer... I put the below code, " request({rejectUnauthorized: true, url : url, headers : {"Authorization" : auth},  method: 'GET',  json: true }" .